# CEGUI includes not showing up in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cegui

Ok, I really have tried to solve this on my own and I'm really at my wits end on this. I cannot for the life of me get the includes from CEGUI to load into visual studio properly. I have experience linking in other libraries such as bullet and ogre but CEGUI just will not work. I have set up everything correctly according to the tutorials online and the various forums I've encountered but nothing has worked thus far. I have included the 3 include folders under "additional include directories" in the C/C++ section of properties. I have included the lib directory in the linker general section and I have included the specific required libraries under linker/input and I have copied the .dll files to my project directory. However, I still cannot get Visual Studio to recognize I have added anything. Every time I try #include  it brings up nothing. Can anyone think of anything I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind on this. I'm really not 100% sure why but after punching in all the settings for what must be the 100th time at this point. the stupid thing compiled no problem. This can be marked as closed.